# Multiple boxplots in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have three vectors for each I would like to make side-to-side boxplots in ggplot2. Each vector contains observations from three separate samples so ideally I would like to identify each boxplot. I know of course how to accomplish that with the simple boxplot command but in ggplot2, it seems to be  more complicated, at least for a newbie such as myself.

Could you please tell me whether there is a painless way to proceed here?

Thank you.

Comment: Some options are here http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/gbe/ggplot_boxplot.htm

Comment: @akrun The problem is that I do not have a data frame and I do not know how to create one that identifies the vectors one by one. I could have used the factor command in the aes() that way.

Comment: It will help if you post your vector data here.

Comment: @rnso This is a generic question, I could post the vector data as well although I do not see how that can be of help.

Comment: Does each vector have the same # of samples?

Comment: @hrbrmstr Yes indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

# re-create your samples via runif (though I should have set.seed first)

obs_1 <- runif(100)
obs_2 <- runif(100)
obs_3 <- runif(100)

# you need a data frame, but you can do it on the fly
# this makes 3 columns from each of your samples
# then uses melt to do wide to long (which is what geom_boxplot needs

gg <- ggplot(melt(data.frame(obs_1, obs_2, obs_3)), aes(x=variable, y=value))
gg <- gg + geom_boxplot()
gg
```

[image]

You should really make a proper data frame, do the melt and rename column as needed. This was just to show a quick example.

Comment: Thank you, that works although I do not fully understand what the melt function does.

Comment: I can expand the answer when off mobile

Comment: For geom_boxplot to work it needs the data in [wide to long](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/reshape.htm) format. `melt` is going to take each column and "melt" it into rows so that `geom_boxplot` can then group the individual readings with that variable/observation name, compute the summary statistics and make the figure. Without other parameters, it'll just take everything and melt it, but you can specify "id" variables that will be associated with each observation as well. Another (longer) explanation [here](http://seananderson.ca/2013/10/19/reshape.html).